# Chaining async calls to MongoDB in nodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, atomic

I have a test that tests an external module which updates the database asynchronously and then immediately I use the (updated) values for the next call. This is done by chaining promises like below.

```
var expectedCateg = 'expected';

ExternalModule.loadUsers(2)
    .then(function firstCallback(){
        return ExternalModule.updateDBAsync(db, expectedCateg);
    })
    .then(function secondCallback(updatedRecord){
        return ExternalModule.readDBAsync(db, categ);
    })
    .then(function thirdCallback(resultCateg){
        if (resultCateg == expectedCateg) {
            console.log("hurray")
        }
    })
```

The ExternalModule that updates the DB async has a few calls like this:

```
exports.updateDBAsync(db, expectedCateg) {
    return Db.getMyDb()
        .updateAsync(
            { $and: [{"keyA": keyA}, {"keyB": keyB}],
              "$isolated": true,
         },
         { $set: {"categ": expectedCateg}},
         {multi: false})
        .then(function success (results) {
           return results
        })
   }
```

This should log "hurray" but it does not, however, if I execute it and then I look in the database manually, using robomongo, for instance, it is updated. This means that when secondCallback is called, the database update operation has *not* finished.

How is this possible? Isn't the point of promises to resolve only when the operation is finished? How can we ensure that control is passed on only after the database update is actually finished?

Comment: Have a look on `updateDBAsync(db, expectedCateg)` in `firstCallback` and `updateDBAsync(expectedCateg)` in your ExternalModule, `updateDBAsync` accepts one argument while you are passing two when you call it. This may be the problem.

Comment: This is a contrived example to illustrate the question, it is not real world running code. I made the edit to the function definition, but that is not the point. It is that I make a MongoDB database update operation and I expect it to be finished after the .then, but it is not. Could this have something to do with the thread-safe-ness of MongoDB update operations?